# How to override the request method (from 'PUT' into 'POST') in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm coding a plugin-wrapper for provide a [app](https://github.com/mgaitan/waliki/) to [restfull](http://www.django-rest-framework.org), problem is the app don't process PUT request, then I get from resfull a PUT request and should change request's method into a POST request.

I have tried this:

```
self.context['request'].method = 'POST'
```

but obviously don't works

How I could do it?
Thanks

## Update:

Serializer code:

```
class PageEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer Class to edit and delete a Page.
    """
    raw = serializers.CharField()

    def save(self):

        #no works
        self.context['request'].method = 'POST'

        """call to waliki new function"""
        views.edit(self.context['request'], self.instance.slug)

    class Meta():
        model = Page
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'raw', )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'slug', )
```

View code:

```
class PageEditView(generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    A simple View to edit a Page.
    """
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    serializer_class = PageEditSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Page.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
```

Comment: Why don't you define PUT method?

Comment: Are you using class based views? Can you explain a little bit more?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña, Yes, Class based views, right

Comment: So you are trying to deceive Django and make all PUT request look like POST, or process PUT request in `django-rest-framework`?

Comment: @LorenzoPeña, Right, I'm trying to deceive Django, or I could use POST request, but I want follow restfull API conventions, so [here](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/)

Comment: Not sure why you need to do that. However this might work: create a custom middleware and implement `process_request`. Just change `request.method` to POST whenever it comes as PUT. Let me know if I should provide a code example of such middleware.

Comment: @LorenzoPeña,  A custom middleware should work, but this takes all requests of my project, does not it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83467/discussion-between-lorenzo-pena-and-rizotas).

Comment: Did the solution work for your case?

Answer (score 8):

I will divide my answer into 3 parts.

**PART-1: Does Django Rest Framework (DRF) explicitly supports request method overriding?**

Yes, DRF has provided 2 ways in which the request method can be overridden.

1. **Using a hidden form field:**

DRF supports browser-based `PUT`, `DELETE` and other methods, by overloading `POST` requests using a hidden form field.

For example:

```
<form action="/some/url" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

In the above example, we have overloaded the `POST` method with `PUT` by using the hidden form field with name as `_method`.

`request.method` will now return `PUT` instead of `POST`.

2. **HTTP header based method overriding:**

DRF also supports method overriding via the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header. Just set the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header with the value of the desired method.

For example, making a `PATCH` request via `POST` in jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/myresource/',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH'},
    ...
});
```

This approach is useful when working with non-form  content such as JSON or when working on an older web server and/or hosting provider that doesn't recognise particular HTTP methods such as `PATCH`.

**PART-2: Why your code is not working?**

Request method is stored in a variable `_method` and the property `method` is used to access the value of it.

Your way of setting value of request method would have worked had there been a `setter` defined for the request's `_method` attribute. Since it is not defined, you can't set the value of request `method` in the way you are doing.

**PART-3: How to override the request method in your case?**

**Solution-1(Quick): Directly set the `_method` attribute**

You can directly set the `_method` to your desired value which will override the request method.

```
class PageEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer Class to edit and delete a Page.
    """
    raw = serializers.CharField()

    def save(self):

        self.context['request']._method = 'POST' # override the request method

        """call to waliki new function"""
        views.edit(self.context['request'], self.instance.slug)

    class Meta():
        model = Page
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'slug', 'raw', )
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'slug', )
```

This will override the request method to `POST`.

**Solution-2: Set `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header in request via middleware**

When `initialize_request()` is called in DRF view, DRF checks for `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header in the Django request. If it is set, it overrides the current request `method` to the method defined in that header.

So before DRF initializes and prepares a DRF `request`, we can set the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header to our desired method which will override the  request method.

We create a `PutRequestMethodOverrideMiddleware` class and set the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header in the request in case the request is `PUT` and this particular header is not already set.

```
class PutRequestMethodOverrideMiddleware(object):  

    def process_request(self, request):  
        override_method = request.META.get('X-HTTP-Method-Override')
        if request.method=='PUT' and not override_method: 
            # Override method in case of PUT requests and header not already set
            request.META['X-HTTP-Method-Override'] = 'POST' # set to desired method value
        return
```

Then in your settings, add this middleware to your `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    ...
    ...
    # your custom middleware 
    'my_project.middlewares.PutRequestMethodOverrideMiddleware',
)
```

But remember, this method will override all the `PUT` requests method to `POST` method.

Here, `PutRequestMethodOverrideMiddleware` will be executed at the end. You can put it at the position you want it to execute.

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain what is DRF?

Comment: @vladimir.gorea DRF is short-form for Django Rest Framework. Apologies for the confusion. Have updated the ans.

Answer (score 1):

As of version 3.3, DRF has [dropped support](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browser-enhancements/) for the method overloading mechanisms via both `_method` form field and `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header. You need to implement it yourself for the latest version.

[The document](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browser-enhancements/) provides an example by adding a custom middleware:

```py
METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER = 'HTTP_X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE'

class MethodOverrideMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST' and METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER in request.META:
            request.method = request.META[METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER]
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Another solution is to override `dispatch` method in each of your `APIView`:

```py
class MyView(APIView):

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'POST' and METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER in request.META:
            request.method = request.META[METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER]
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Could you add an example-implementation to this answer? I see there is one in the DRF docs.